# linux + find + delete files on remote machines except particular files

Tags: bash, find, rm, remote

we have redhat 7.2 Linux version

I want to remove on remote machines all repositories files under 
`/etc/yum.repos.d` except the following files under /etc/yum.repos.d

```
local.repo
redhat.repo
cluster.repo
```

we tried this ( but without success )

```
ssh root@$machine find /etc/yum.repos.d  -type f -not -name 'local.repo ' -or -name 'redhat.repo' -or -name ' cluster.repo’  –delete
```

or

```
ssh root@$machine find /etc/yum.repos.d  ! -name 'local.repo|redhat.repo|cluster.repo' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

or

```
ssh root@$machine find   /etc/yum.repos.d -type f -not \(-name 'local.repo'  -or -name 'redhat.repo' -or -name 'cluster.repo' \) -delete
```

Comment: Your sequence of `-or ...` should be wrapped in parentheses

Comment: this is not duplicate , this is diff question we want to delete files on remote machine and exclude some files ,

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh "root@$machine" '
   find /etc/yum.repos.d -type f ! \(
     -name local.repo -o \
     -name redhat.repo -o \
     -name cluster.repo \) –delete
'
```

(assuming the login shell of the root user on `$machine` is Bourne-like).

Remember what you're passing to `ssh` is not the arguments of a command to run on the remote host, but a string that is interpreted as shell code by the login shell of the remote user. So the easiest is to put that string inside single quotes so the local shell doesn't interfere with it.

Comment: what you think about my answer , its similar to your answer

Comment: @yael, yes that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

this CLI will remove all files under /etc/yum.repos.d , exclude the files , and also will print the files that are deleted

```
ssh "root@$IP" "find  /etc/yum.repos.d ! -name local.repo ! -name redhat.repo ! -name cluster.repo    -type f -delete -print"
```